# How can i get last letter from edit text and put it in adapter

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-arrayadapter

I have a delete button which deletes text in an EditText, and the value of the EditText is the item clicked in a RecyclerView. Now when I delete text from edit text it disappears from the adapter. Now how can I return it back to adapter after clicking on delete?

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
    edit.setText(edit.getText() + adapter.getItem(position).toString().toUpperCase());
    edit.toString().toUpperCase();

    MediaPlayer  mediaPlayer2=MediaPlayer.create(Ridles.this,R.raw.zagonetkebutonklik);
    mediaPlayer2.start();
    suggestSource.remove(adapter.getItem(position));

    simpleArray = new String[suggestSource.size()];
    suggestSource.toArray(simpleArray);
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    int numberOfColumns = 5;
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, numberOfColumns));
    adapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(this, simpleArray);
    adapter.setClickListener(this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
    adapter.notifyItemChanged(position);
    adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(position,suggestSource.size());
    lvl.setText("lvl: " +String.valueOf(curquestion));

}
public void obrisi(){
    String text=edit.getText().toString();
    if(text.length()>=1){
        edit.setText((text.substring(0, text.length() - 1)));
        edit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this to get the text from `EditText`:

```
String text = edit.getText().toString();
```

And get the last letter like this:

```
String lastL= text.substring(text.length() - 1);
```

Then set the value as follows:

```
edit.setText(lastL);
edit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: yea but it is any reverse method,to just take this letter and put it to arrayadapter

Comment: No . This is not a reverse method.

Comment: I expressed myself wrong i ment to say is there any reverse method,now i took last letter but i want to put it in adapter.But it doesnt work

Comment: Why you need to delete the item if you are just replacing the letter?

Comment: THnx man,i was wondering how to now take from edit text and ad to adapter,bcs when click on adapter items those items populate edittext,now when somebody delete item from edit text i want to get it back to adapter,but i have no idea which logic to use

Comment: That's why you need to use viewholder method for you recyclerview.

Comment: i did it finaly,I had interface for click events so i couldnt use viewholder ,but thnx man for your time,all best

Comment: I will ask you not to forget to accept it, by clicking the checkmark (✔️) on the left side under the vote arrows. Should change the color in green. I'd appreciate it. Thanks! :D

Comment: And also edit your question with the details so newbie's can get the answer. :D

Answer (score 0):

You could just get the text from `EditText`:

```
String text = edit.getText().toString();
```

Then you can get the last character like this:

```
String lastString = text.substring(string.length() - 1);
```

Comment: Well, the `char` was provided just as an option with the String. So yeah your right your answer is positive.